# How to access object array using javascript with variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, internationalization

```
var dict = {
  "configMigratedTo": {
        "message": "Migrated configuration to configurator: $1"
    }
}
var parametersForTranslation = {};
function __tr(src, params) {
  parametersForTranslation[src] = params;
  return buildMessage(src);
}

function buildMessage(src){
    var message=dict[src] ? dict[src].message : src
    console.log(message);
    var messageArray = message.split("$");
    var output = "";
    messageArray.forEach(function(elem, index){
        if(index === 0){
            output += elem;
        }else{
            // get variable and index
            var paramIndex = configMigratedTo.substring(0, 1);
            var paramValue = parametersForTranslation[src][paramIndex-1];
            output += paramValue;
            output += configMigratedTo.substring(1);
        }
    });
    return output;
}
__tr("configMigratedTo", [2]);
console.log(buildMessage("configMigratedTo"));
```

i want get result like __tr("configMigratedTo", [2]);
then it will give me

Migrated configuration to configurator: 2

i do not know where is wrong in my code

Comment: What is `__tr()` ?

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette it's a function, defined above, in code.

Comment: basically, it means find translation according to the key...__tr means translation

Comment: Ha. ok. But you mess on the source. You want to access `configMigratedTo` in the `dict` object. It should be something like : `dict.configMigratedTo.message` to get the value `Migrated configuration to configurator: $1`... Now I really don't know if the $1 will taken in account as a variable... That depends on the `buildMessage()` function And I can't tell just like this.

Comment: Your code fails at line 22: `configMigratedTo` is not defined.

Comment: i try to write a function like get chrome.i18n.getMessage("click_here", ["string1", "string2"]);     chrome.i18n.getMessage json file looks like that "configMigratedTo": {
        "message": "Migrated configuration to configurator: $1"
    }  and it works by calling chrome.i18n.getMessage..i just want to rewrite this function..

Comment: Well, before you can play around with programming logic you need a solid foundation of programming (JavaScript, in this case) basic concepts. And from trying to access a variable which has not yet been defined it looks like you should focus on the latter. Do you understand the difference between the missing variable `configMigratedTo` var and the existing property on the `dict` object?

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu Thanks, i see you point..now i understand it better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one. Hope it helps!

```
var dict = {
  "configMigratedTo": {
        "message": "Migrated configuration to configurator: $1"
    }
}

function __tr(src, params) 
{
    for (var key in dict)
  {
    if (key === src)
    {
        var message = dict[key].message;
        return message.substring(0, message.length - 2) + params[0];
    }
  }
  return;
}


console.log(__tr("configMigratedTo", [2]))
```

https://jsfiddle.net/eLd9u2pq/

Answer (score 1):

Would that be enought?

```js
var dict = {
  "configMigratedTo": {
        "message": "Migrated configuration to configurator: "
    }
}

function buildMessage(src,param){
    var output = dict[src].message + param;
    return output;
}

console.log(buildMessage("configMigratedTo",2));
```

Answer (score 1):

You are overcomplicating this, it's much easier using a regex and passing a function as replacer

```js
var dict = {
  "configMigratedTo": {
    "message": "Migrated configuration to configurator: $1"
  }
}
function __tr(src, params) {
  if (! dict[src]) return src;
  if (! /\$0/.test(dict[src].message)) params.unshift('');
  return dict[src].message.replace(/\$(\d)+/g, (orig, match) => params[match] || orig);
}

console.log(__tr("configMigratedTo", [2]));
```